# How to include Date / Timestamp into my features

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I'm creating a decision tree model and I'm training it with a dataset.

However, some of the columns in this dataset are either **TimeStamps** or **Date**. I've been going through Apache's documentation and haven't been able to find a way to parse or add this values into my `features` column.

Any idea of how I can do it?

Comment: Quite often there's no point in using those fields for a classifier. Are you sure you have useful features in those fields?

Comment: Yeah. Usually the end user will put which columns to look for anomalies when my program is running. A possible scenario can be that if a date in a column is past a certain threshold, that value should be considered as bad, and my decision tree needs to see and understand why that value is wrong, which is why I need to include the date in my features vector

Comment: @user8371915 it's no duplicate because nobody answered that question. That answer hasn't been accepted, and also the solution posted there is for Scala only, not Python.

Comment: just convert your datetime to a unix timestamp! did you tried this?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to transform them into features. One way is to create dummy variables with things like year, Month, week, or even weekend, hours. It depends what features you want to create for your problem.

Comment: That might work but it will require a lot of processing, specially because timestamps also have hours, minutes, and seconds. I thought of converting the timestamp to an Integer, but idk how reasonable is that

Comment: Yeah that is why it depends on you specific problem, if you care about only hr in the day then you can extract the hours from your time stamp and create 24 dummy variables with all the hours in there. With dates you can create also several features, weekend/not weekend, day of the week(1-7), month (1-12) etc etc. Now if your problem needs details to the minute and second of the time, you can also turn the time of the day into an integer counting seconds from the 0 hr, for example, that might help.